# ways to hide secret in png image (steganography)

Tags: png, steganography

I'm trying to find a secret message, a string, in a 256x256 png image. It's supposed to have  "used an old school trick to hide the data", and apparently that method is mentioned in the steganography Wikipedia article.

I tried what appeared to me as most oldschool an straightforward first: LSB steganography. But no luck. I know the first and last characters of the string ("F" and "}"), and I thought they may have mixed the common lsb method up a bit, so I inspected the very first pixels and the very last pixels of the picture myself. However, no apparent combination (like only red values of each pixel) would allow for the correct character. Hence I'm pretty positive it's not using lsb.

In a second, rather desperate try I saw that Wikipedia talks about stripping the most significant six bits, leaving only the least significant two, and then normalizing the picture. I wrote a little script to do this, but no luck here either.

I also looked at the metadata with `identify -verbose image.png`. Nothing. The file ends as it should after the IEND chunk, so nothing hidden beyond that either.

I'm running out of ideas, so here my question:

Any hints what might classify as old school trick, that I haven't already tried? I'm sure I missed something obvious. This exercise came with a few others, and they all looked harder at first glance than they really were.

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: There are countless ways of hiding data in a PNG - plus another set of countless *variations* of each as well. Your LSB attempt, for example: did you assume the bits are stored left-to-right, top-to-bottom, most significant bit first?

Comment: I know there's countless ways, but the fact that it's supposed to be "old school" should narrow that down quite a bit. I hope. And I did try both most and least significant bit first. Most significant first worked with other implementations. I did not try top-to-bottom though. Either way, the first three bits (first pixel) would already not fit the first expected character (that is supposing the data starts right at the beginning of course).

Comment: Try this: print out the least significant bits in the exact order you are reading them now. That should give you a matrix of 3*256x256 `0`s and `1`s. Scan by eye if you detect a pattern -- left-right, top-down, or any other order.

Comment: .. I'm wondering if it would be useful if you posted the image. Chances are *someone* is going to crack it in no time, but then again, there are always people who think they should "give you the code" - or, even worse, just say what secret phrase is.

Comment: This question is off-topic because what is regarded here as "old school" is subjective, because there is more than one possibility, even if the pool of options is small. This is also not exactly related to a coding problem. The [Crypto Stack Exchange site](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) may be more relevant to this. Regarding your question, I wouldn't be so quick to rule out LSB embedding, because, even though the method is standard, you can mix it up in many ways and the only way to figure it out is to get really dirty with the raw data and find some patterns.

Comment: @Jongware I'm trying to avoid that. I really don't want somebody to solve it for me. Just a little discussion and a few hints what other methods could be meant. I'll try the printing out tonight though, sounds fun ^_^.

Comment: @Jongware Ok I now tried a whole bunch of other things, among them  vertical, red/green/blue bits only, and I even looked at diagonal. While I'm going to these lengths I can't help but think I missed something more obvious, more simple. As I mentioned earlier, this is an excercise from a batch of six, and the others I already finished were all really rather straightforward, often you just had to see something from the right angle, but it wasn't really too complicated. This makes me assume that in all likelyhood they won't have used some funky bit pattern here. I might be wrong though..

Comment: When you look at the LSB, are you expecting for the hidden text to appear as an image, or as a binary (say, ASCII) code of bits?

Comment: @leonbloy I am expecting it to appear as ascii code. However, in my desperation I did try and remove the first 6 bits and then normalize (as mentioned on Wikipedia - after all they claim Wiki mentions the used trick). Nothing but noise, though. Maybe I should try to use just the last bit. I don't see Wiki mentioning anything but lsb for hiding data in pictures by the way, which is why I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @Jongware The picture is a 256x256 version of Lenna. I just created a Lenna png that size from the original from Wikipedia (which is 512x512). Here is the normalized difference of the two(no apparent block of differences at either top or bottom border): http://i.imgur.com/oYsOB4D.png

Comment: I found a 256px png of lenna that did not have the slight offset this one has, and I substracted those two. The result is something that seems like a bit code in the middle of the picture. It's not a straightforward ascii code though, so I'll have to see about that. Still, one step further, found the secret. Thanks for your hints. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that there was a chunk in the middle of the picture with a long text, which contained the wanted string, hidden in the least bits of the blue values only, in least bit first order. Somehow I missed that combination in my preliminary tests. So there you go. :)

To anybody having a similar problem: I find it's best to write a script to test all more commonsense variations (like only single colors, vertical, least-bit or greatest-bit first, etc.) in one large run. It's too easy to miss a simple one otherwise and get hopelessly stuck in crazy complicated theories.

Comment: Hi @foaly, I am trying to extract a flag from a png file, but not lenna. The hint is "used an old school trick to hide the data" too. (Maybe we were study in the same school). I tried find the original picture and diff-ed them with tools. there's a block in the middle of the picture too. But I have no luck to figure it out how bits store. Do you have any suguestion?

Comment: I solved it, it's using multiple channels to store a long text.

Comment: OP or @Tim Hsu can you explain in detail how you solved it? diego.serra.brigante@gmail.com! Thank you I have the same problem with a .png file.

Comment: could you send me a sample file, maybe it is not the same image

Comment: pass me your email or send me one to mine please :)

Comment: a common way is to search google images for that exact image.  If you find the exact image, you then just compare the bytes of the pixels.